Python html date module fetching incorrect date
I am trying to fetch publication date from a few hyperlinks using the htmldate module but it is fetch incorrect date for a few articles. For example https://blog.cloudflare.com/ja4-signals was published yesterday on 12-08-2024 however the result that I get is 2024-06-27. Below is my code
import requests
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from htmldate import find_date

data = []

def process_url(url):
    try:
       response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
       response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for non-200 status codes
       html = response.content.decode('utf-8')
       date = find_date(html)
       return {'Hyperlinks': url, 'Date': date}
    except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ValueError) as e:
       print(f"Error occurred while fetching data from {url}: {e}")
    return None

   with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
       results = executor.map(process_url, result_df["Hyperlinks"])

for i, result in enumerate(results, start=1):
    if result:
        data.append({'Serial Number': i, **result})
        print(f"Serial Number {i}: The date for {result['Hyperlinks']} is 
{result['Date']}")
   else:
        print(f"Serial Number {i}: Error occurred while fetching data from a URL")

AllHyperlinks_V2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

The hyperlink in result['Hyperlinks'] is "https://blog.cloudflare.com/ja4-signals". I am not able to understand the problem. It is working fine for most of the hyperlinks while failing to fetch correct result for a few. Can someone help ?

the htmldate library is not working properly, it's returning the date from one of the images instead, try using another library or writing your own solution.

think you should take a look a the page source and see what date is actually being returned - as there are a bunch of dates embedded within that page.
